# Xcode: After removal of framework - "Linker command failed with exit code 1"

Tags: xcode, path, linker, frameworks

I tried to install the Charts framework for my application but for some reasons things wouldn't work. Therefore, I decided to remove it from the application in order to reinstall a different version, but now I get an error when building:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/antonkallbom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Aiida-dwnonkyfsunbssdfeglitwzmrecb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Charts'
>   ld: framework not found Charts
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

So I guess I need to remove the path somehow in order to be able to build the project? I tried deleting all the filed in DerivedData, but without success.

I saw some similar problems where you were supposed to remove the paths from "Framework Search Paths", but I don't seem to have it in Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

The setting is within `Build Settings`:

[image]

Search for "Search Paths" and you should see Framework Search Paths...

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! Apparently it was set to "Basic" instead of "All". However, I found the search path for Charts and removed them all but the problem is still there. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you clean the project again after removing it?

Comment: Yes, I did. I also Charts included in "Other Linker Flags". After removal of the flag, I now get "Shell Script Invocation Error" with ".../DerivedData/Aiida-dwnonkyfsunbssdfeglitwzmrecb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Aiida.app/Frameworks/Charts.framework: No such file or directory".

Comment: "I also removed Charts..." * in my previous comment. Removed it from "Other C Flags" as well, but without any success.

Comment: Try searching for `linker` in build settings... if you don't see any references there then you might have to mess with the build script a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally got it working! :)

There were flags included in .debug.xcconfig and .release.xcconfig, as well as some additional paths in -frameworks.sh. After removing them, it works!

Should have thought about searching the whole project earlier... Thanks for the help!